# accessing wssid and the guid of managed meta data using silverlight 

Tags: managed-metadata, silverlight, client-object-model

I am making a silverlight UI to allow users to enter information into a list.  I want give the users a choice of metadata to enter into the list,  but in order to enter the metadata into the list, I need the GUID and wssid, which I do not seem to get from using TaxonomyClientService.  I tried using TaxonomyHiddenList, but that only gives you information about metadata that is being used.  Does anyone have any other proposed solutions?  When you use the silverlight client object model, you cannot use Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create **a custom Web service** to expose appropriate methods from the `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Taxonomy` namespace.